# Prove the equivalence of the matrix $2$-norm and $\infty$-norm.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Prove the equivalence of the matrix $2$-norm and $\infty$-norm. That is, for $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$ prove that there exist constants $c_1,c_2$ such that $c_1\|A\|_\infty \leq \|A\|_2 \leq c_2\|A\|_\infty$.

*proof* [right side inequality]

First note that for $y \in \mathbb{C}^n$ that

$$ \|y\|_2 
= \sqrt{\sum_{j =1}^n |y_j|^2 }  
\leq  \sqrt{\sum_j^n \left( \max_{1\leq j \leq n}|y_j|^2 \right)}    
= \sqrt{\sum_j^n \left( \max_{1\leq j \leq n} |y_j| \right)^2 } 
= \sqrt{\sum_j^n \|y\|_\infty ^2 }   
= \sqrt{n \|y\|_\infty ^2 }
= \sqrt{n} \|y\|_\infty$$

This shows that for arbitrary $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$ that $||Ax||_2 \leq \sqrt{n}\|Ax\|_\infty$. Now, here's where I'm running into issues. I need to show that

$$\sup_{\|x\|_2 =1} \|Ax\|_2 \leq \sqrt{n} \sup_{\|x\|_\infty=1} \|Ax\|_\infty$$

But the sets over which we are taking the supremum is not the same set. I am wondering, is it always true that if

$$f(x) \leq c_1g(x)$$

for all $x$ is it also true that

$$ \sup_{x \in A} f(x) \leq c_1 \sup_{x \in B}$$

But anyway, I know this for a fact

$$\sup_{\|x\|_2 =1} \|Ax\|_2 \leq \sqrt{n} \sup_{\|x\|_2=1} \|Ax\|_\infty$$

But I don't know how to justify the supremum being montone over a unit ball.

---

*proof* [left inequality]

Here I'm having similar issues. I can show that for a vector that $\|Ax\|_\infty \leq \|Ax\|_2$ so I have pretty much the same situation (I believe), and that I'm stuck on relating the supremums. I obviously have these two

$$\sup_{\|x\|_2 =1} \|Ax\|_\infty \leq \sup_{\|x\|_2=1} \|Ax\|_2$$

or

$$\sup_{\|x\|_\infty  =1} \|Ax\|_\infty \leq \sup_{\|x\|_\infty=1} \|Ax\|_2$$

but not

$$\sup_{\|x\|_\infty  =1} \|Ax\|_\infty \leq \sup_{\|x\|_2=1} \|Ax\|_2$$

Comment: Unrelated Latex tip: use `\|` instead of `||` to delimit norms.

Comment: You can solve the latter case by rewriting the supremum over $\|x\|_p \le 1$, for a given norm (why should the suprema be the same?), and noting then that $\|x\|_\infty \le \|x\|_2 \le 1$.

Comment: In the first case, you can use the fact that unit ball in 2 norm is a subset of a unit ball in $\infty$ norm. Also, if you do not need to know the constants $c_1$, $c_2$, you can skip this proof and say that the matrix space is finite dimensional and every norm is therefore equivalent.